# MobileFirst create wrong SMS request

Tags: sms, ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0.0.
After configuring SMS settings I am trying to send a message but the request is created in the wrong way. See the result below.

//REST API : send notification request

```
{
   "message": {
       "alert": "Hello World from an SMS message"
    },
    "notificationType":3,
    "target" : {
        "deviceIds" : ["9a149c24-8859-3383-6067-d161e46d2554"]
    }
}
```

The created request:

```
473607:[2017-01-02 16:44:02.494] - [440093822] Request received: HTTP GET /send.aspx?
encode=false&name=toParamName&value=Recipients&encode=false&name=textParamName&value=MessageText&encode=false&name=MessageType&value=text&encode=false&name=SenderName&value=PLIX&encode=false&name=UserName&value=MahmoudSamy&encode=true&name=Password&value=xyz&to=20100051111&text=Hello+World+from+an+SMS+message+2
```

//SMS settings

```
{
  "port": "80",
  "programName": "/sendsms",
  "host": "xyz.com",
  "name": "SMSGateway",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "toParamName",
      "value": "to"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "textParamName",
      "value": "text"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "SenderName",
      "value": "Support"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "UserName",
      "value": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "encode": "false",
      "name": "Password",
      "value": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below configuration works with me but it force me to accept to and text parameters.

```
{
    "port": "80",
    "programName": "/sendsms",
    "host": "xyz.com",
    "name": "SMSGateway",
    "parameters": [{
        "SenderName": "Support",
        "MessageType": "text",
        "UserName": "xyz",
        "Password": "xyz"
     }]
}

HTTP GET /send.aspx?SenderName=Support&MessageType=text&UserName=xyz&Password=xyz&to=083127312763&to=hello+world
```

Answer (score 1):

We tried to send SMS with SMS settings shared by you.
We are able to get correct value pair in the created request. 
Below is the created request

GET /gateway/add.php?encode=false&name=toParamName&value=to&encode=false&name=textParamName&value=text&encode=false&name=SenderName&value=Support&encode=false&name=UserName&value=xyz&encode=false&name=Password&value=xyz&to=99&text=Hello+World+from+an+SMS+message HTTP/1.1

Also in created request shared by you, I am noticing different username value than given in sms settings.

Could you please tell us how you are checking the request. We are using wireshark to capture.